# Unable to run confluent Kafka platform

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am following this [tutorial](https://docs.confluent.io/current/tutorials/examples/microservices-orders/docs/index.html?_ga=2.80282647.1605358191.1555036134-544987551.1555036134).

And as instructed, I have downloaded the platform from [here](https://www.confluent.io/download/), and cloned the github repository for code.

Downloaded platform is in zipped form, so I unzipped it and added its bin folder to PATH system variable.
Now, I try to run start.sh as asked in 'Exercise 0: Run end-to-end demo'. But nothing happens.

A command window pops up and immediately disappears.
What am I missng here?

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial assumes you're already in a terminal and typing those commands.

Sounds like you're simply clicking the shell script, and there's some error

Comment: Windows CMD? Confluent Platform is not supported on Windows, so I doubt that tutorial will run okay there

Comment: Sure. You can use a Linux VM or Docker